# Qgis OpenStreetMap plugin misbehaviour

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins

I used the plugin successfully.
But yesterday, after changing several buildings in JOSM.
Import under qgis with the plugin does not work anymore.
The buildings are in the layer point!
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. To make it easier for people to provide information that will help you, can you please tell us a bit more about your configuration and the problem? You can just click "edit" (above) to amend the question. Things you might like to include are details of the version of QGIS and the plugin that you are using (with links to where you got it), the platforms you are using it on (e.g. windows, mac, linux), a link to the data that you are trying to display (where in the world, for OSM), and a more complete description of the problem. If only an image will do, perhaps a link?

Comment: I can reproduce the behaviour, and it is platform-independent. The OpenStreetMap plugin is more or less broken, since it does work with 64-bit-node-ids.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the missbehaviour is that Openstreetmap have crossed the border of 2^31 nodes: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/64-bit_Identifiers, making it necessary for all programmers to change ids form int to 64-bit-int. I guess that is not yet implemented in the plugin. It will be rewritten for QGIS 2.0, so you have to wait until that is released.

Here an example of Mapnik map:[image]

and what the plugin renders: [image]

Comment: Sorry for my comment (10 10... It is painful) Hi, thank you for these hypothesis.
I do not fully understand the first reason.
By cons I edit with josm I sent to the server. And again I download qgis with the server.

Can you check the last hypothesis? Finding the number of nodes?

When QGIS version 2.0 you will get it? http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Release_Roadmap
There is there an alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Ok, forget my first hypothesis. I just looked up a few things I added last week, and they are not shown after downloading, but they are present in the mapnik map. There is still a large number of open tickets, and it may take to April or later.

Comment: A new version of the plugin is just around the corner, but probably only available for QGIS Master.